# OData grouping entities

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'm trying to have the following urls

- `v1/$metadata`
- `v1/se/companies`
- `v1/se/addresses`
- `v1/no/companies`
- `v1/no/addresses`

But if i use `[ODataRoutePrefix("se/Companies")]` i get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The path template 'se/Companies({companyNumber})' on the action 'Get' in controller 'SwedishCompany' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'se'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.GetODataPathTemplate(String prefix, String pathTemplate, IServiceProvider requestContainer, String controllerName, String actionName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<GetODataPathTemplates>b__1(ODataRouteAttribute route)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.BuildAttributeMappings(IEnumerable`1 controllerActions)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.get_AttributeMappings()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataActionSelector.SelectCandidates(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Route.OnRouteMatched(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Is there some way to add a prefix with a `/`?